# How to move a text label to the top of a table view cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, cell

I've been trying to move a textLabel to the top of a table view cell but it won't move. How do I move the textLabel to the top of the cell?

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:25.0];
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15.0, 41.0, 257.0, 97.0);


[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:5];
```

Comment: i think you need to layout your own custom cell to achieve what effort you want.

Comment: create your own custom tableViewCell it will be cleaner and easier to modify than changing the frame of a built in cell label